# How to clear the FullCalendar cache events

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

After drop an event from an external list and save this event on me server side i keep seeing the dropped event which is not in my source array.

I tried a lot of solutions to clear events using `EventSources` as in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647783/fullcalendar-v4-clear-all-events), but what is happening is that all the events who came from the API are cleared but not the one who I dropped the blue one (CACHED).

In action : I have already `red event` in my view, and I add another `red event` from my drop list, but after the drop you will see the `new red event` that I add + another `blue event (CACHED EVENT)` this blue event is not in my source event list.

Using `calendar.getEventSources()` to clear the event is clearning only the event from the API, results is like this

[image]

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

CODE :

```
    import React, { Component }             from "react";
    import $                                from 'jquery';
    import moment                           from 'moment';
    import { Trans }                        from 'react-i18next';
    import { DebounceInput }                from 'react-debounce-input';
    import FullCalendar                     from '@fullcalendar/react';
    import dayGridPlugin                    from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
    import timeGridPlugin                   from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
    import listPlugin                       from "@fullcalendar/list";
    import interactionPlugin, { Draggable } from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
    import { Module }                       from '../Calender/Module';
    import { CalendarLoad }                 from '../../../../../Util/Svg';
    import  { getFlyerById }                from '../../../../../Util/Api/Cms';
    import { withAlert }                    from 'react-alert';

    import "@fullcalendar/core/main.css";
    import "@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css";
    import "@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css";
    import "@fullcalendar/list/main.css";

    import './CalendarV4.css';

    class CalendarDemo extends Component 
    {
      calendarComponentRef = React.createRef()

      state = {
        modalData: null,
        isModalOpen: false,
        eventReceiveStartDate: null,
        isEventinTheView: null,
        isEventinTheViewValue: ''
      };

      componentDidMount() 
      {
        const draggableEl = document.getElementById("externalEvents");

        new Draggable(draggableEl, {
          itemSelector: ".draggable-events",
          eventData: function(eventEl) 
          {
            const title = eventEl.getAttribute("title");
            const id = eventEl.getAttribute("id");
            const duration = eventEl.getAttribute("data-duration");

            return {
              title: title,
              id: id,
              duration: duration
            };

          }
        });
      }

      eventDrop = info =>
      {
        const string = info.event.title;
        const stringId = string.split(' - ')[0];
        const id = parseInt(stringId)

        this.props.schedulesEvent(id, info.event.start, info.event.end)
      };

      eventReceive = info =>
      {
        this.setState({ eventReceiveStartDate : moment(info.event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD") })
        this.props.addToCalendarHandler(info.event.id, info.event.start , info.event.end);
      };

      drop = info => 
      {
        if ($('#RemoveAfterDrop').is(':checked')) {
          $(`#externalEvents #${info.draggedEl.id}`).each(function() {
            $(this).remove();
          })
        }
      };

      eventClick = info => 
      {
        const string = info.event.title;
        const stringId = string.split(' - ')[0];
        const id = parseInt(stringId)

        this.setState({ isModalOpen: true });

        getFlyerById(info.event.id).then( res => {
          this.setState({ modalData: {...res.data ,eventId: id} });
        })

      };

      eventResize = info => 
      {
        const string = info.event.title;
        const stringId = string.split(' - ')[0];
        const id = parseInt(stringId)

        this.props.schedulesEvent(id, info.event.start, info.event.end)
      };

      datesRender = info => 
      {
        const viewActiveStart = moment(info.view.activeStart).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        const viewActiveEnd = moment(info.view.activeEnd).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        const range = `${viewActiveStart}/${viewActiveEnd}`    

        this.props.datesRangeHandler(range);
      }

      deleterFlyer = id => 
      {
        this.setState({ 
          modalData: null,
          isModalOpen: false
        });

        this.props.deletingEventHandler(id)    
      }

      modalToggleHandler = () => 
      {
        this.setState({ isModalOpen : false, modalData: null})
      };

      isEventinTheView = id => 
      {
        const calendar = this.calendarComponentRef.current.getApi();

        this.setState({ 
          isEventinTheView : calendar.getEventById( id ) === null ? false : true,
          isEventinTheViewValue: calendar.getEventById( id ) === null ? 'No' : 'YES'
        })

        if ( id === '' ) {
          this.setState({ isEventinTheViewValue : '' })
        }
      };


      testingAndDebugging = () => {
        const calendar = this.calendarComponentRef.current.getApi();
          let eventSources = calendar.getEventSources(); 

          for (var i = 0; i < eventSources.length; i++) { 
              eventSources[i].remove(); 
          }             
      };


      render() 
      {
        const { modalData, isModalOpen, isEventinTheViewValue, isEventinTheView } = this.state;
        const { modifiedEvents } = this.props

        return (
          <div>

            <FullCalendar
              plugins={[
                dayGridPlugin,
                timeGridPlugin,
                listPlugin,
                interactionPlugin
              ]}

              header= {[{
                center: "title",
                right : "today prev,next",
              }]}

              firstDay           ={1}
              timezone           ="UTC"
              defaultView        ="dayGridMonth"
              editable           ={true}
              droppable          ={true}
              selectable         ={true}
              eventLimit         ={true}
              forceEventDuration ={true}
              events             ={modifiedEvents}

              drop             ={this.drop }
              eventDrop        ={this.eventDrop}
              eventClick       ={this.eventClick}
              eventResize      ={this.eventResize}
              datesRender      ={this.datesRender}
              eventReceive     ={this.eventReceive}

              ref              ={this.calendarComponentRef}
            />

            <Module
              modalData            ={modalData}
              isModalOpen          ={isModalOpen}
              deletingEventHandler ={this.deleterFlyer}
              modalToggleHandler   ={this.modalToggleHandler}
            />

            <div className="calendarNotLoad">
              <CalendarLoad />
            </div>

            <div className="mt-5">
              <h4 className="mt-4 mb-4"><Trans>Is this Flyer ID exist in this view</Trans></h4>
              <DebounceInput
                className={`calendar-flyer-search ${isEventinTheView ? 'green' : 'red'}`}
                type="text"
                placeholder="Search for a Flyer in this month"
                minLength={1}
                debounceTimeout={700}
                value={ isEventinTheViewValue }
                onChange={ e => this.isEventinTheView(e.target.value) }
                onBlur={ () => this.setState({ isEventinTheViewValue : '', isEventinTheView : null })}
              />

            </div>

            <div className="text-right">
              <button className="btn mt-5 fc-prev-button fc-button fc-button-primary" onClick={ this.testingAndDebugging }>calendar.getEventSources()</button>
            </div>

          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default withAlert(CalendarDemo)
```

I add a button with a test function to start a playing around with the calendar functionality, and end up with two groups `WORKING & NOT WORKING` functions, like.

```
testingAndDebugging = () => {
 const calendar = this.calendarComponentRef.current.getApi();

 // WORKING EVENTS
 //===============
 calendar.render();
 calendar.refetchEvents();
 calendar.addEventSource(modifiedEvents);
 calendar.batchRendering(function() {
 calendar.changeView('timeGridWeek');
 })
 calendar.getEventSources();
 calendar.on('dateClick', function(info) {
 console.log('clicked view ' + info.view );
 });

 // NOT WORKING 
 //===============
 calendar.removeEventSource();
 calendar.removeEvents();
 calendar.removeEvents(10157);
 calendar.removeEvent();
 calendar.removeEvent(10157);
}
```

Comment: Please show your code as well. We can't fix code we can't see. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson it is already inside the full details question that i mentioned  in my post  (i axplaned that in detailes in longer question ) Thanks

Comment: You can't split between multiple questions, that can potentially make this post off topic, or a candidate to be a duplicate, and get closed. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, you should anyway try and make it easy for people to help you - copy the relevant details here, so that it's all in context together. Thanks

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for the advice, i added my code here