# FullCalendar 4, clear events before refetching

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

First, I've seen this: [Fullcalendar V4 - clear all events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647783/fullcalendar-v4-clear-all-events)

But the docs for 'remove()' say: Removes all events associated with this source ***and prevents it from being fetched again***.

If I do this:

```
$("#possibleStaff").on('change', function(){
    var sources = calendaring.calendar.getEventSources();
    sources[0].remove();
    calendaring.calendar.refetchEvents();
});
```

The refetchEvents is ignored.

Is there a `clear everything without removing the source` command?

The particular problem I'm trying to work around is if I add an event and then refetchEvents, the added event is still present until I completely reload the page. That's why I'm looking for a 'clear-all'.

Current work around:

```
calendaring.clearAll = function(){
  $.each(calendaring.calendar.getEvents(), function(key, event){
    var thisEvent = calendaring.calendar.getEventById(event.id);
    if(thisEvent) {
      thisEvent.remove();
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: There is no direct function, no. I can think of a couple of other ways to work around it which might be a bit more efficient. But, just quickly, why do you want to clear this independently added event? Does it not get saved to your server before that anyway?

Comment: P.S. you could make your workaround more efficient as well: `calendaring.clearAll = function(){ var events = calendaring.calendar.getEvents();
$.each(events, function(key, event){
        event.remove();
    }
})};` - it's better not to call getEvents() repeatedly, and you don't need to fetch the event again by its ID - you've already got it in `event`, so you can just remove it directly.