# fullcalendar version 4: refetch events doesn't remove newly added event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I'm using fullcalendar version 4, and I've added a custom button to 'refresh' the calendar with current information/events.

Here's my button:

```
 customButtons: {
        myReloadButton: {
            text: 'refresh',
             click: function() {
                    calendar.refetchEvents();
                    calendar_mini.refetchEvents();
               }
            }
```

I have two calendars that I want to refresh as you can see.  It works fine, but I notice an issue.  When I create a new event, it's added to the calendar as it should.  However, if the user clicks the 'refresh' button right afterwards then the just-added event shows up twice once the events are re-loaded.  It seems the newly added event was never removed during the refresh.

I have a modal form that opens to gather information for the event. Once the event is saved, here's how I am saving it (via an ajax call). In the success of the ajax, I am adding the event to my calendar with .addEvent()

```
 var location_id = $('#formEventModal #location_id').val();
 var saw_by_id= $('#formEventModal #saw_by_id').val();

$.ajax({
            url: "ajax_insert.php?table=appointments",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#appointmentForm').find(':input').not('.dont_serialize').serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.success) {

                    //get the inserted id of the appt just added so it can be updated on the stop if needed.
                    var lastInsertID = response.lastInsertID;

                    var event_object = {
                        id: lastInsertID,
                        location_id: location_id,
                        resourceId: saw_by_id,
                    };

                        calendar.addEvent(event_object);
                        calendar_mini.addEvent(event_object);
```

Why is it that the refresh button doesn't remove newly added events?

Comment: did you try this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56650657/9246297

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that refetching events just reloads events from a defined source. It doesn't have any effect on standalone events which are not attached to a source.

There are two ways to address this

One solution is to replace `calendar.addEvent(event_object);` in the  AJAX "success" function with simply  `calendar.refetchEvents();` - then it immediately reloads from the server, which will include the newly added event, instead of adding a separate standalone event to the calendar directly.

Another option is to attach the event to the source when adding it to the calendar. The [Add Event documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent) says

> `source` represents the Event Source you want to associate this event
>   with. It can be a string Event Source ID or an Event Source Object.
>   When the source is refetched, it will clear the dynamically added
>   event from the internal cache before fetching. This parameter is
>   optional.

So if you gave your event source an ID when you declared it, you could place that here as an extra option to associate the event with the source. Something like this:

```
calendar.addEvent(event_object, 1);
```